# How to convert spark dataframe to ArrayByte suitable for hbase bulk put?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I am working on hbase project, where we have to ingest data into HBase.
We read file received and get those data as dataframe.

Now I have to convert that dataframe to Array[Byte], Array[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])]).

So that I can perform bulk put on hbase.

Say I have a dataframe like below

```
case class Employee(key:String, name:String, address:String)
val df = Seq(Employee("1","abc","xyz"),Employee("2","def","xyz")).toDF()
df.show()
```

| key | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | xyz |
| 2 | def | xyz |

What is the efficient way to convert this dataframe to RDD[Array[Byte], Array[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])])] to store in HBASE using bulk put.

Note : Assume key is tagged with rowkey of hbase. Assume some random CF and column name to populate RDD

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-write-using-hbase-spark-connector/

Comment: Some restrictions In environment. We tried that approach.

Comment: Can you give the sample output you want and be a little clearer pls?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain it better than this: https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/62/Spark/BulkLoadingHBasewithSpark.html

It's all there.

Comment: Thanks.. here in this example they are showing direct RDD creation.. I need to convert my dataframe to RDD[Array[Byte], Array[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])])]  for saving in hbase.  Please help me in how to do thay conversion part. Thank you.

Comment: I think it goes a whole end in explaining.